# Microsoft Software H264 Encoder Produces Progressively Degrading Quality

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I have a functioning encoder using Media Foundation, which uses hardware acceleration. I have decided to add Microsoft's software H264 encoder as a fallback if hardware acceleration is for some reason not available.

The problem I have, is when I begin streaming from the encoder, the quality starts off fine and then rapidly degrades until nothing is readable/viewable at all. This seems to be triggered the moment there is any motion. **This problems only exists when I use the software encoder**. When I am using any of the hardware encoders, it may degrade for a moment when there is movement, but it quickly restores the quality somehow.

## Here is a frame before any sort of movement:

[image]

## Here is how it looks after any movement occurred:

[image]

## Here is my encoder configuration

```
HRESULT configure_encoder(const CComPtr<IMFTransform>& in_transform, CComPtr<IMFDXGIDeviceManager>& in_device_manager,
    const DWORD in_input_stream_id, const DWORD output_stream_id
)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Sets or clears the Direct3D Device Manager for DirectX Video Acceleration (DXVA)
    if (FAILED(hr = in_transform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER, reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(in_device_manager.p))))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to enable DXVA acceleration for encoder";
        //return hr;
    }

    // Create output type
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> output_type;
    if (FAILED(hr = MFCreateMediaType(&output_type)))
        return hr;

    // Set output type
    if (FAILED(hr = output_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = output_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = output_type->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, encode_bitrate)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = output_type->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_High)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = MFSetAttributeSize(output_type, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, encode_width, encode_height)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(output_type, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 60, 1)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = output_type->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlaceMode::MFVideoInterlace_Progressive)))
        return hr;

    // Set output type
    if (FAILED(hr = in_transform->SetOutputType(output_stream_id, output_type, 0)))
        return hr;

    // Input type
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> input_type;

    if (FAILED(hr = in_transform->GetInputAvailableType(in_input_stream_id, 0, &input_type)))
        return hr;

    // Input type settings
    if (FAILED(hr = input_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = input_type->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = MFSetAttributeSize(input_type, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, encode_width, encode_height)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(input_type, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 60, 1)))
        return hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = input_type->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlaceMode::MFVideoInterlace_Progressive)))
        return hr;

    // Set input type
    if (FAILED(hr = in_transform->SetInputType(in_input_stream_id, input_type, 0)))
        return hr;

    std::cout << "- Set encoder configuration" << std::endl;

    // AMD encoder crashes on this line
    /*DWORD flags;
    if (FAILED(hr = inTransform->GetInputStatus(0, &flags)))
        return hr;*/

    return hr;
}
```

I tried tampering with the following codec API attributes hoping something would change, I wasn't able to make any noticeable difference.

````
// Get Codec API pointer
ICodecAPI* mpCodecAPI = NULL;
if (FAILED(hr = encoder_transform->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&mpCodecAPI))))
return hr;

VARIANT var;

// Set mode to CBR
var = { 0 };
var.vt = VT_UI4;
var.lVal = eAVEncCommonRateControlMode_CBR;
if (FAILED(hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, &var)))
return hr;

var.vt = VT_BOOL;
var.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
if (FAILED(hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode, &var)))
return hr;

var = { 0 };
var.vt = VT_UI4;
var.lVal = 100;
if (FAILED(hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, &var)))
return hr;

var = { 0 };
var.vt = VT_UI4;
var.lVal = 4;
if (FAILED(hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncVideoMaxNumRefFrame, &var)))
return hr;

var = { 0 };
var.vt = VT_UI4;
var.lVal = 0;
if (FAILED(hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncMPVDefaultBPictureCount, &var)))
return hr;

var = { 0 };
var.vt = VT_UI4;
var.lVal = 0;
if (FAILED(hr = mpCodecAPI->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize, &var)))
return hr;```
````

Comment: Take a look at the [Tutorial: Using the Sink Writer to Encode Video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--using-the-sink-writer-to-encode-video#initialize-the-sink-writer) which encode static video frames to a file.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT This is literally the first thing I looked at when I being using Media Foundation. Can you explain how a tutorial on encoding a green static frame would help me fix a problem that is dependent on the source frames having movement? Lol

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Answer (score 0):

The software encoder isn't set in your code.

```
    CComPtr<IMFAttributes> attrs;
    MFCreateAttributes(&attrs, 0);
    attrs->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, false);
    hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(file, NULL, attrs, &pSinkWriter);
```

Comment: Firstly, I am not using a SinkWriter. I am using an IMFTransform. Secondly, according to MSDN, even if I was using a SinkWriter, "By default, the source reader and sink writer do not use hardware decoders or encoders. To enable the use of hardware MFTs, set this attribute to TRUE when you create the source reader or sink writer". i.e,I wouldn't have to disable it, because it is disabled by default. I don't want to sound offensive or rude - but not only does your answer not help at all, it doesn't even appear to be correct information.

Comment: No I am not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mf-transform-async-unlock This is what I am using if it is a hardware MFT.